# Force rows to get a certain value on a dummy

Tags: r, replace, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe (lmr_sak) with verdicts from criminal cases in the Norwegian Court of Appeals from 1993-2019. On the 1st of October in 2015 a new criminal law (Straffeloven 2005 [not a typo, it took 10 years to come in to force]) replaced the old one from 1902.

I want to create a dummy for whether a verdict utilized the old or new law. First, I created a dummy based on the dates:

```
lmr_sak$dato <- as.Date.factor(lmr_sak$dato)


lmr_sak <- lmr_sak %>% 
  mutate(strl1902 = ifelse(dato > "1993-01-04" & dato < "2015-10-01",1,0))
```

But the problem is that some of the verdicts after 2015-10-01 still used the old law (because the alleged crimes were committed before 2015-10-01), resulting in verdicts getting the wrong values on 'strl1902'.

Luckily, in my df I have a column 'paragraf' which I think can help remedy the problem. Examples of its contents are:

- 'Straffeloven (1902) §99'
- 'Straffeloven (2005) §93'
- 'Straffeloven 1902 §9'
- 'Straffeloven 2005 §77'

What I wish to do is to force the rows with the strings (1902) or 1902 to get 1 on 'strl1902', and rows with (2005) or 2005 to get 0.

I imagine that I can do it with piping the code above, and maybe use ifelse(), replace() and a form of regex, but I'm very uncertain of what to do...

ANSWER:

Thanks to @Skaqqs suggestion, this ifelse with multiple logic did the trick:

```
lmr_sak_match$strl1902 = ifelse(lmr_sak_match$dato > "1993-01-04" & lmr_sak_match$dato < "2015-10-01", 1,
                                ifelse(grepl("1902", lmr_sak_match$paragraf),1,0))
```

Comment: Hi @Torkel, I'm glad you were able to solve your problem. If my answer was correct, please click the green arrow next to my answer to accept it as so. Or, if your answer is preferred, feel free to add it as an actual answer (rather than an edit to your question), and mark it as correct. This closes the question and makes it easier to find for future readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a regular expression, like this:

```
lmr_sak$strl1902 <- grepl(pattern = "Straffeloven.*1902", x = lmr_sak$paragraf)
```

If you want to include date in your logic as well, you can do so like this:

```
lmr_sak$strl1902 <- (lmr_sak$dato > "1993-01-04" & lmr_sak$dato < "2015-10-01") &
  grepl(pattern = "Straffeloven.*1902", x = lmr_sak$paragraf)
```

And you can wrap this in an ifelse() if you wish to use 1 and 0 as values for your dummy variable.

```
lmr_sak$strl1902 <- ifelse(
    test = (lmr_sak$dato > "1993-01-04" & lmr_sak$dato < "2015-10-01") &
        grepl(pattern = "Straffeloven.*1902", x = lmr_sak$paragraf),
    yes = 1, 
    no = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This ifelse with multiple logic did the trick:

```
lmr_sak_match$strl1902 = ifelse(lmr_sak_match$dato > "1993-01-04" & lmr_sak_match$dato < "2015-10-01", 1,
                                ifelse(grepl("1902", lmr_sak_match$paragraf),1,0))
```